# About const array parameter in c language

Tags: c

I have been learning c language by knking book.
I have question about `const` array parameter.
Book says ordinary variable is passed to function, its value is copied. So any changes to corresponding parameter don't affect the variable.
In contrast an array used as an argument isn't protected against change.
Therefore, we use `const` to protect array parameter as below;

```
int find_largest(const int a[], int n)
```

`a` is a pointer to first element of array `a`, `a[0]`.
Then I want to know whether `const int a[0]` means protecting only `a[0]` from modification or protecting subsequent array elements from modification also?

Comment: Frankly I doubt that you have seen a prototype as with `const int a[0]` anywhere. It would mean an array of size 0, i.e. it would not be legal to access anything in that array and even the declaration should make most compilers scoff.

Comment: Zero size arrays aren't valid C, though some compilers use them as (obsolete) non-standard extensions. Please clarify what you mean with `const int a[0]`.

Comment: @종투더지 The qualifier const is used in declarations. You can not declare an element of an array apart from the whole array.  So this record const int a[9] does not make a sense.

Comment: Function parameters of type  `T[]` (for some type `T`) get "adjusted" to `T*`, so the parameter `const int a[]` gets adjusted to `const int *a`. This means that none of `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[i]` etc. (or `*a`, `*(a+1)`, `*(a+i)` etc.) are modifiable through pointer `a`.

Answer (score 3):

A declaration `const int a[]` declares `a` to be an array whose elements have type `const int`. The `const` qualifier applies to all elements.

When this declaration is used as a declaration of a function parameter, it is automatically adjusted to be a declaration of a pointer, `const int *a`. When pointer arithmetic is used with this pointer, the result is a pointer of the same type. Thus `a+0`, `a+1`, and `a+2` are all pointers of type `const int *`.

Subscripts are defined in terms of pointer arithmetic, so `a[0]`, `a[1]`, and `a[2]` are all expressions of type `const int`.